# Passport.authenticate throw Unauthorized error iwith cookies approach

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Passport.authenticate throw Unauthorized error with cookies approach.
Where can be problem, in passport js settins or on frontend side?Interesting that on compyter another developer it works fine

nodeJS

```
router.post('/check',passport.authenticate("cookie", { session: false }), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json({ status: true })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
});
```

frontend

```
export async function isAuthorized(context, commands) {
let token = getCookie('token')
if (token) {
    let settings = {
        "method": 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },

    }

    try {
        let response = await fetch('/api/auth/check', settings) //here unathorized
        let result = await response.json()
        return result.status
    } catch (error) {
        throw Error
    }
} else {
    return false
}
```

}

the cookie is sent successfully with this
maybe I need use some additional settings for passport or something like this